# Docker: Error: Unable to access jarfile lib/sonar-application-7.6.jar

Tags: docker

Upon creating a container using docker-run after creating an image using Dockerfile for SonarQube-7.6, I am getting this error after running `docker logs <container-name>`

> Error: Unable to access jarfile lib/sonar-application-7.6.jar

I think the user permission is incorrect but not sure where am I going wrong.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV SONAR_VERSION=7.6 \
    SONARQUBE_HOME=/opt/sonarqube \
    # Database configuration
    # Defaults to using H2
    # DEPRECATED. Use -v sonar.jdbc.username=... instead
    # Drop these in the next release, also in the run script
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar \
    SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=

# Http port
EXPOSE 9000

RUN groupadd -r sonarqube && useradd -r -g sonarqube sonarqube

# grab gosu for easy step-down from root
RUN set -x \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.10/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/1.10/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && (gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
        || gpg --batch --keyserver ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4) \
    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && gosu nobody true

RUN set -x \
    # pub   2048R/D26468DE 2015-05-25
    #       Key fingerprint = F118 2E81 C792 9289 21DB  CAB4 CFCA 4A29 D264 68DE
    # uid                  sonarsource_deployer (Sonarsource Deployer) <infra@sonarsource.com>
    # sub   2048R/06855C1D 2015-05-25
    && (gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys F1182E81C792928921DBCAB4CFCA4A29D26468DE \
        || gpg --batch --keyserver ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys F1182E81C792928921DBCAB4CFCA4A29D26468DE) \
    && cd /opt \
    && curl -o sonarqube.zip -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION.zip \
    && curl -o sonarqube.zip.asc -fSL https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION.zip.asc \
    && gpg --batch --verify sonarqube.zip.asc sonarqube.zip \
    && unzip sonarqube.zip \
    && mv sonarqube-$SONAR_VERSION sonarqube \
    && chown -R sonarqube:sonarqube sonarqube \
    && rm sonarqube.zip* \
    && rm -rf $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/*

VOLUME "$SONARQUBE_HOME/data"

WORKDIR $SONARQUBE_HOME
COPY run.sh $SONARQUBE_HOME/bin/
USER sonarqube
ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, it was a user permission error, in line:

`chown -R sonarqube:sonarqube sonarqube`

Used a different home path, SONARQUBE_HOME= /xyz
for setting the user permission, I used:

`chown -R sonarqube:sonarqube xyz`

Replaced this with,

`chown -R sonarqube:sonarqube /xyz`

It worked for me!!!!!